# images inside function array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, image

I am working on a Star Wars turn based click game. The played is meant to pick 1 of 4 of the available characters that randomly is picked from an array of 6 characters.

I have a couple questions:
   1 is this image link going to do anything is I am able to target it?

2 how do I turn `Characters();` into a usable array

```
function Character(name, health, attackPoints, counterAttackPoints, img) {
  this.name = name;
  this.health = health;
  this.attackPoints = attackPoints;
  this.counterAttackPoints = counterAttackPoints;
  this.img = img;

  console.log(name, attackPoints, counterAttackPoints);
}

var char1 = new Character('Han Solo', 100, 13, 10, '../assets/images/Han_Solo_depicted_in_promotional_image_for_Star_Wars_(1977).jpg');
var char2 = new Character('Chewbacca', 300, 10, 20, '../assets/images/Chewbacca-2-.jpg');
var char3 = new Character('Luke Skywalker', 140, 15, 12, '../assets/images/Luke_Skywalker.png');
var char4 = new Character('Darth Maul', 120, 12, 13, '../assets/images/Darth_Maul.png');
var char5 = new Character('Darth Vader', 175, 20, 6, '../assets/images/Han_Solo_depicted_in_promotional_image_for_Star_Wars_(1977).jpg');
var char6 = new Character('General Grievous', 120, 14, 10, '../assets/images/Han_Solo_depicted_in_promotional_image_for_Star_Wars_(1977).jpg');
```

Comment: 1. How can we know if  you can do anything with it? All you are showing is a string. 
2. Just push your characters into an array. 

This question isn't very clear.

Comment: `var characterArray = [char1, char2, char3, char4, char5, char6]`?? Is this what you want? Your first question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
var somethingNew = new Character(...)
```

You could push the new character into an array:

```
var characters = [];
characters.push(new Character('Han Solo', 100, 13, 10, '../assets/images/Han_Solo_depicted_in_promotional_image_for_Star_Wars_(1977).jpg'));
characters.push(new Character('Chewbacca', 300, 10, 20, '../assets/images/Chewbacca-2-.jpg'));
// etc

console.log(characters.length); // 2!

console.log(characters[0].name); // Han Solo
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly, you are trying to turn an object into an array of some kind.

you can use the Object.values()

```
const char1 = {
  name: 'Some Dude',
  health: 100,
  attackPoints: 13,
  counterAttackPoints: 10, 
  img: '../some/url/to/your/asset.jpg'
};

console.log(Object.values(char1)); 

// Output will be => ["Some Dude", 100, 13, 10, "../some/url/to/your/asset.jpg"]
```

if you need to go deeper into the object like looping inside the object prototype, then you will need to opt for a `for .. in` loop

Comment: That seems very unlikely that this is the purpose of the OP, since they start out by a list like your result (provided as function arguments).